# Boostrap grid two column layout to drop under each other on small device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am strugling with a layout in bootstrap.

On normal desktop environment I have this layout

```
________col1________________col2_________
|firstname + input  |  Email + input    |
|lastname + input   |  Telephone + input|
|etc                |                   |
-----------------------------------------
```

When the page is viewed on mobile, I would like column 2 to drop under column 1. At the moment email gets pushed under firstname. The order becomes firstname, email, lastname, telephone, etc

Here is the html I have so far. It's probably simple to solve this, but so far no luck. In the below code my rows are of course a problem, but wrapping it in two col-xx-6 columns doesn't work somehow

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">Bedrijfsnaam</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">Straat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" data-bind="with: address">
        <span data-bind="text: street"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">E-mailadres</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span data-bind="text: email"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">Nummer</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" data-bind="with: address">
        <span data-bind="text: number"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">Website</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span data-bind="text: website"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">Achtervoegsel</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" data-bind="with: address">
        <span data-bind="text: numberext"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">KvK nummer</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span data-bind="text: coCnumber"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">Postcode</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" data-bind="with: address">
        <span data-bind="text: postalcode"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with Bootstrap's Grid System. The following will work for you

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- column 1 stuff here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <!-- column 2 stuff here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

What the above does is create two columns that will be floated next to each other on larger displays but will collapse to rows when the resolution becomes less than 750px (the breakpoint Bootstrap has chosen for `col-sm-*`.

Don't forget that Bootstrap requires you to wrap your content within a `.container` class. More info here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container